# How to secure Carrierwave uploads to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I've read the security section of the Carrierwave docs. However, they relate to attachments uploaded to the public folder, while I'm using Carrierwave and Fog to upload PDFs to AWS. How can I ensure these PDFs can only be downloaded by someone clicking a download link within my web app?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714508/rails-carrierwave-private-files-on-s3-and-cloudfront/18800662#18800662