# How to setup private files with S3, CloudFront and Carrierwave

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Currently I have an S3 Bucket with an access policy that only allows access from a CloudFront Origin Access Identity:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This should prevent any access to the S3 asset which is not through the CloudFront distribution.

However when I input the S3 url into my web browser I can still access the file.

I am using Carrierwave and Fog to upload files to S3 and have `config.fog_public = true` so I believe what is happening is that Fog is putting a public access setting on the uploaded object.

I tried changing the setting to `config.fog_public = false` but that then started returning signed URL's that ignored my `asset_host` setting (so provided the signed S3 URL rather than the unsigned CloudFront URL).

I presume I need to keep `config.fog_public = true` and have an S3 bucket policy that overrides the public access setting that Fog is putting on my objects.

Can anyone advise if that is correct or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: You should set `fog_public` to false, to ensure the files are private outside your other settings. Then, instead of calling `url`, which differs based on the `fog_public` setting, call `public_url` which should always return asset_host style urls.

Details:

`config.fog_public = true` does 2 things:

1. set public readable when the files are created
2. return public-style urls for reading

whereas `config.fog_public = false` does two different things:

1. set public readable to false when files are created
2. return private/signed-style urls for reading

Unfortunately you want 1/2 of each approach, which the `url` within carrierwave doesn't directly support.

I think you will probably want to leave `config.fog_public = false` in order to ensure the files are private as you desire, but you may have to get the urls differently in order to have them show up with the seemingly public urls you desire. Normally the usage of carrierwave suggests you should use `url` to get what you want, and this has branching logic based on the `fog_public` setting. You can skip over this logic and just get the asset_host url though, by just calling `public_url` instead.

All that said, out of my own curiosity, if the files will be publicly available via CDN anyway, why would they need to be private via S3?

Comment: Im looking at Carrierwave::Uploader::Base but didn't find #public_url. Did you mean another library?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to configure per model (one public, another private): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800662/5945650